# Upgrading older CQ 5.5 Blog components to AEM 6.2

Tags: adobe, upgrade, aem, blogs

I am working on an old small site built on CQ 5.5  In this older implementation they have copied the Out of the Box Blog components into the apps folder.  It looks like they copied them out of the box Blog page component into the apps folder and customized it. This component uses a lot of older API's. I have listed some of them below. Most of these are not present any more in AEM 6.2. As a sample, I have also given the feed.jsp which is a part of a blog page. The feed uses Atom feed renderer for blog and blog entry nodes.

There is also a lot of content they built using these blog templates. Can anyone please advice how can I upgrade these components and how I can migrate this content. Is there a one on one replacement for these API's? Also, any ideas how I can migrate the blog content.

```
                 com.day.cq.rewriter.linkchecker.LinkCheckerSettings,

                 com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMMode"

               com.day.cq.collab.blog.Blog,

               com.day.cq.collab.blog.BlogManager,

               com.day.cq.collab.blog.BlogEntry,

               com.day.cq.collab.blog.BlogEntryFilter,

               com.day.cq.collab.blog.TagEntryFilter,

               com.day.cq.collab.blog.AuthorEntryFilter,

               com.day.cq.collab.commons.Comment,

               com.day.cq.commons.ProductInfoService,

               com.day.cq.commons.ProductInfo,

               com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMMode,

               org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource,

               org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver,
```

Comment: I formatted code as far as I tried, if something more to be formatted, please edit it, it will help members to understand your question and provide a solution.

Comment: _This software is the confidential and proprietary information of Day Management AG, ("Confidential Information"). You shall not disclose such Confidential Information and shall use it only in  accordance with the terms of the license agreement you entered into with Day._
You literally just posted this code on a public website. I'm no lawyer but this looks like a rather obvious violation of this license.

Comment: Deleted the Jsp File.